# RequireJS not hiding KnockoutJS bindings until loading of everything complete

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

#### tl;dr

The issue I am seeing is my initial page (Index.cshtml) has some Knockout code (indexViewModel.js) that is called that initially *should be* hiding a div on load, but for a few brief seconds the div is indeed **not** hidden b/c the Knockout code hasn't evaluated yet.

---

### Background & Issue

I just began refactoring my site to use **RequireJS**. It is an ASP.NET MVC 5 application which uses KnockoutJS, jQuery, and a few jQuery & JavaScript plugins.

Everything worked great prior to the RequireJS refactor. Now when the user loads the Index, the spinner (`data-bind="showSpinner"` which is false) is shown to the user for about 3 seconds and then the Knockout code is loaded and realizes it should be hidden so then it hides.

So I am wondering how to prevent this "flashing" of hidden elements from happening? In Angular you could do `ng-cloak`, but I haven't found that equivalent for Knockout or Require.

I know there are some hacks I could do to initially hide things until all modules are loaded, but I don't want to hack my entire application just so things are hidden by default.

### My code

Here is my basic setup for my site, using RequireJS, Knockout, jQuery, & ASP.NET MVC.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div data-bind="showSpinner">
    <img src="/Content/spinner.gif" />
</div>

<!-- at the bottom of my Index.cshtml I have this section below 
    which renders the script at the very bottom of the entire DOM, via
    ASP.NET MVC `render scripts`-->

@section scripts 
{
    <script>
        var d = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        require( [ "/Scripts/app/common.js" ], function() {
            require( [ "app/offers/index"], function(view) {
                view.init(d);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**common.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts/",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-1.11.2",
        "underscore": "underscore.min",
        "knockout": "knockout-3.3.0.debug",
        "komapping": "knockout.mapping-latest",
        "noUiSlider": "jquery.nouislider.all",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap" 
    },
    shim: {
        "komapping": {
            deps: ['knockout'],
            exports: 'komapping'
        },
        "noUiSlider": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: '$'
        },
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});
```

**index.js**

```
define(['knockout', 'app/offers/indexViewModel'], function (ko, mvm) {
    return {
        init: function (modelData) {
            var vm = modelData;
            mvm.addMethods(vm);
            ko.applyBindings(vm);
        }
    };
});
```

**indexViewModel.js**

```
define(['knockout', 'jquery'], function (ko, $) {
    return {

        addMethods: function (viewModel) {
            viewModel.showSpinner = ko.observable(false);
            //then a bunch of other KO code, but that observable above is the first thing & i use some jQuery plugins below, that's why i load in jQuery
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try marking the content as "display: none;" in either a stylesheet or an inline style.  Then use Knockout's "visible" binding to control the visibility.  The content will be hidden until Knockout has a chance to evaluate, setting the visibility to whatever your Knockout logic dictates.

RequireJS is probably loading your scripts asynchronously, so the markup is rendering before your JavaScript has a chance to execute.  Therefore you'll need a synchronous way to hide the content until your JavaScript executes.

ngCloak uses the exact same trick: there is a CSS selector that hides any elements with the ngCloak attribute until Angular's JavaScript has a chance to execute.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: That is the "hack" I was thinking of (might not necessarily be a hack, I just wasn't sure if there was a more eloquent way of doing it). Although maybe this is the *only* way to accomplish it. I'm hoping to find another way though, I'm sure someone else out there has encountered this. I also thought it was possible my code above was wrong or could be tweaked. Either way, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, you could wrap the behavior you want into a custom binding called "cloak", for example.  Then your code could look something like `<div data-cloak data-bind="cloak, click: foo" />`.  Still not quite as clean as Angular.

Comment: External stylesheet did not work for me, but inline none did